# Angular: How to sort nested array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have nested array that i need to sort by `age`. Means if any female age largest of any male age then female goes first.

```
 data = {"people": 
   [{"male": [
     {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}, 
     {"name":"Mike", "age":"22"}
    ]}, 
    {"male_two": [
     {"name": "Rob" ,"age": "12"}, 
     {"name":"Tom", "age":"2"}
    ]}, 
   {"female": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"}, 
     {"name":"Ann", "age": "43"}
   ]}, ...
   ]}
```

So in my case i need to return:

```
data = {"people": 
   [{"female": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"}, 
     {"name":"Ann", "age": "43"}
    ]}, 
    {"male": [
     {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}, 
     {"name":"Mike", "age":"22"}
    ]},
    {"male_two": [
     {"name": "Rob" ,"age": "12"}, 
     {"name":"Tom", "age":"26"}
    ]}, ...
    ]}
```

Can i use angular `$filter` for?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `orderBy`-function.

`$filter('orderBy')(array, expression, reverse)`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

> function: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted
>   using the <, ===, > operator.

```
$scope.customOrder = function(gender) {
    var highestAge = 0;
    for(person in gender) {
        if(gender[person].age > highestAge) {
            highestAge = gender[person].age;
        }
    }
    return highestAge;
}
```

You can either use this in an `ng-repeat` attribute:

`ng-repeat="g in people.gender| orderBy:customOrder"`

Or with the `$filter`-Service ( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter ).

The code above is untested but i hope you get the point.